# how to add the following lines in my c++ project in vs2013

Tags: c++, windows, manifest

in this link: [target application for windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx), except for a .manifest file, there is a next step to do to add the following lines to my sources.

```
SXS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID=1
SXS_MANIFEST=foo.manifest
SXS_ASSEMBLY_NAME=Microsoft.Windows.Foo
SXS_ASSEMBLY_VERSION=1.0    
SXS_ASSEMBLY_LANGUAGE_INDEPENDENT=1
SXS_MANIFEST_IN_RESOURCES=1
```

But I really don't know where to add these lines in my c++ project in vs2013.

Comment: I have been looking for the same too. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: No one answered me, so I didn't add these lines. However, It worked well.